# WSL on Windows 10 shows weird files that don't exist when ls is used

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ubuntu-18.04, wsl2

When I `cd` to Desktop on WSL on Windows 10, and do `ls`, it shows a large amount of files that is not there on my machine. I even tried showing the hidden files but it is not them. When I try to use `sudo rm` for those files, WSL just crashes. What are those and is there a way to not see them when `ls` is run?

Comment: Are you referring to all the files in the image? Or just some of them?

Comment: @DavidPostill all the visible files in the image except the Zoom and This PC shortcuts

Comment: Please [edit] your question and copy&paste the `cd` and `ls` commands and the resulting output including the prompts *as text* and format this as a code block.

Comment: And Welcome to Super User.  Please see [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11810933) for the reasons why we ask that you not post text as images.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm curious - You never accepted my answer, but was that the reason for the files?  I've deleted my answer for the reasons I mentioned in the comment earlier.